# How to build qemu with additional machine types

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, libvirt

I'm trying to migrate around 40 KVM VMs (containing a few hundred live snapshots mostly used for automated testing on Windows) from a Ubuntu 22 server to a Debian 11 server. The machine type of most of the VMs are `pc-i440fx-xenial` and I've tried changing the XMLs to machine type `pc-i440fx-5.2` to match an available machine type on Debian but qemu only accepts this for shutdown snapshots - trying to run any live snapshots with this change throws an error.

In an attempt to resolve this, I would like to try building a version of qemu on Debian that includes the `pc-i440fx-xenial` machine in it. The problem is that the documentation I've found is not very noob friendly (I don't have much experience with emulation aside from fairly high level things), so I am not sure exactly how to build qemu aside from the basic instructions here: https://wiki.qemu.org/Hosts/Linux#Running_QEMU_on_Linux

So what I'm wondering is how specifically I can extract the `pc-i440fx-xenial` from a Ubuntu build, and how to include this in a qemu build. There was a similar question asked here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54394543/how-to-add-more-supported-machine-types-to-qemu However, it does not give much instruction on how to actually build it with the extra machine type. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: a snapshot shouldn't be portable across architectures. Not sure how you'd imagine that would work – you save the state of the virutalized hardware, but then go ahead and just replace the kind of hardware? So, you're on the right path. The easiest way forward to get a piece of software the way that Ubuntu built it is building the same source code, using the same patches and whatnot. Thus, simply do a source rebuild of the qemu-kvm packages (.deb files) of Ubuntu on/for your target debian. Ubuntu has done all the work of specifying how that is built automatically already :)

Comment: Ok that makes a lot of sense.  I'm not exactly sure what a source rebuild entails, but I did try installing a Ubuntu qemu-kvm .deb file (https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/qemu-kvm) on Debian (re-compressing the .deb file contents for Debian).  It did not throw and error and unpacked over the Debian qemu-kvm i think? `Unpacking qemu (1:6.2+dfsg-2ubuntu6.6) over (1:5.2+dfsg-11+deb11u2) ...`  However, the machine types in the `qemu-system-x86_64` emulator found in `/usr/bin/` still do not show the Ubuntu ones.  Am I doing this correctly or am I way off track?